# why I can run my asp.net site on local iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have local iis7 on my machine. there are two application running on it: web service and asp.net site.
until yesterday it had worked perfectly, but today suddenly when I run it I get this error:

unable to start debugging on the web server.
the underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred on a send.
click help for more information.

when I build it I don't see any problem.

what can be the problem?

Comment: Try changing the web site to use a port other than 80

Comment: where can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

See the "Tray Icons".....and 
Right click on the webserver Icon->exit/close....
then run your application or

Or

restart your computer.....causes your IIS will restart...

More Information :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599

Tray area in desktap
[image]

Comment: where I find tray icons? I am afraid I didn't understand.

Comment: I restarted  my computer, did not help.

Comment: the problem has been solved. I don't know why it happened and I don't know how it solved.